# Firebase Function not triggering when data added to database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to have my code create a notification for another user when it is updated in the database, however it does not seem to be triggering and nothing appears in the log. I can see the value in the database being written.

Is there something that I am missing in my code? I know that the path is correct.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
'use strict'

var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {


 const user_id = context.params.user_id;
   const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

   console.log('We have a notification to send to : ', user_id);
  
 if(!change.after.val()){
    
     return console.log('A notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);
  
 }
  
   const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');
  
   return deviceToken.then(result => {
      
       const token_id = result.val();
        
       const payload = {
            notification: {
                title : "Friend Request",
                body : "You-ve recieved a new Friend Request",
                icon : "default",
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

            console.log('This was the notification feature');

        });
    
    });

});
```

Edit: Since I cannot add an image here is the best I can do to describe it. In the database we Notifications. Within Notifications, when someone tries to add a friend, it populates it with the user_id of that person who would receive the request. With in that persons user_id it then adds a randomly generated notification_id where in that part it has both the user who sent the request and the type of notification. Below is a little diagram

- Notifications
- --->user_id
- ------>notification_id
- --------->from
- --------->type

Comment: Please edit the question to be specific about how exactly you are making the change, and how show that it the change does match the wildcard pattern in your function.

Comment: Thanks, I have added an edit to my question which should hopefully help clear up what is going on in the database to better troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1):

The function trigger should not use template strings, but literal strings:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}").onWrite((change, context) => {
```

By using a template string (with variables that are undefined) you're triggering on `/Notifications//` and your `context.params` collection will be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That makes sense however it still does not appear to be triggering. Maybe I am missing something else or messed up where it is calling, however I have triple checked that. Is it at all possible I am missing a line of code needed?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error with your string interpolation to me.

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref(`/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}`).onWrite((change, context) => {
```

Should be

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref(`/Notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).onWrite((change, context) => {
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This did not work and it appears to still not be triggering.

Answer (score 0):

You are not authenticating your Admin SDK to Firebase.

```
var serviceAccount = require("./your-secret-service-key.json");

//admin.initializeApp();
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://your-project.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Comment: Those settings are no longer needed in recent versions of Cloud Functions for Firebase. They are now auto-derived from the Google Cloud Platform environment. See e.g. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#review_complete_sample_code